# Simple document using FastReport.Net does not show text

Tags: c#, .net, fastreport

I tried to make a simple document using FastReport. So I started with placing a button on the form and writing the following code in order to run it when the button is clicked:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Report report = new Report();
    ReportPage page1 = new ReportPage();
    page1.Name = "Page1";
    report.Pages.Add(page1);

    page1.ReportTitle = new ReportTitleBand();
    page1.ReportTitle.Name = "ReportTitle1";

    TextObject text1 = new TextObject();
    text1.Name = "Text1";
    text1.Text = "REPORT TITLE TEXT";
    text1.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;
    text1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
    page1.ReportTitle.Objects.Add(text1);

    report.Show();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I ran the application and I pressed the button, a blank page was shown, without any text. What is wrong with the code? Does it lack some element?

Answer (score 1):

You should set width and height for text object:

```
text1.AutoWidth = true;
text1.Height = 100;
```